# how to get all open issue from easy redmine using api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redmine-api

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.easyredmine.com/");

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{

    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("issues/{id}.xml{?include}"))
    {

        string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check documentation https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues

Answer (score 0):

in this link you can found the API documentation of Redmine:
https://easyredmine.docs.apiary.io/

However, you can take all issue list with this url:
http://www.easyredmine.com/issues.xml

You have to create the model to map the result of the call and then with linq you can filter the list of objects obtained.

The model of reponse is this:

```
<issues total_count="1" offset="0" limit="25" type="array">
    <issue>
        <id>765</id>
        <project id="71" name="Administration"/>
        <tracker id="13" name="Other"/>
        <status id="1" name="Planned"/>
        <priority id="12" name="High"/>
        <author id="5" name="Andrew Smith"/>
        <assigned_to id="5" name="Andrew Smith"/>
        <subject>issue subject</subject>
        <description>
            issue description
        </description>
        <start_date>2014-04-11</start_date>
        <due_date>2014-04-11</due_date>
        <done_ratio>0</done_ratio>
        <estimated_hours>1.0</estimated_hours>
        <easy_email_to>test@test.com</easy_email_to>
        <easy_email_cc>test@test.com</easy_email_cc>
        <created_on>2014-04-11T08:24:47Z</created_on>
        <updated_on>2014-04-11T08:24:47Z</updated_on>
        <closed_on/>
        <sprint id="1" name="Sprint" due_date="2014-04-11"></sprint>
    </issue>
</issues>
```

I think you’ll have to filter through the 'status' field